# two dimensional array skipping values

Tags: java

I am trying to read in a file into a two dimensional array character by character and I have a code that does that, but after the first line of characters is read, it sets nothing to the next space in the array and then sets the character that's supposed to be in that space one space ahead. How do I fix it?

```
   for(int x = 0; ((c = br.read()) != -1) && x < w.length*w.length; x++) {
     w.currentChar = (char) c;
     w.row = x/w.length;
     w.column = x%w.length;
     w.wumpusGrid[w.row][w.column] = w.currentChar;
     System.out.print(w.currentChar);
     System.out.print(w.row);
     System.out.print(w.column);
   }
```

Comment: What is `w`?  An object?

Comment: Clearly w represents the current state of the Hunt the Wumpus game. :)
More here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_the_Wumpus

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the '\n' at the end of the line is being read and assigned to your array, you need to skip the character and keep a count of the skips to you can offset for skipped characters:

```
int offset = 0;
for(int x = 0; ((c = br.read()) != -1) && x < w.length*w.length; x++) {
  if (c == '\n') {
    offset++;
    continue;
  }
  int pos = x - offset;
  w.currentChar = (char) c;
  w.row = pos/w.length;
  w.column = pos%w.length;
  w.wumpusGrid[w.row][w.column] = w.currentChar;
  System.out.print(w.currentChar);
  System.out.print(w.row);
  System.out.print(w.column);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a BufferedReader to read a line at a time from your source file, and construct each row of your array one by one then.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in line endings (`'\n'` (linux/mac) or `'\r\n'` (win)) and treating them as your chars. You are increasing `x` despite of what char was read. Take `x++` out of the last part in `for` definition and move it at the end of loop body. At the beginning of the loop `continue` if `c == '\n' || c == '\r'` (I guess both chars are not interesting to you)